# Is there a C code analyzer which can show usage of global variables in functions?

Tags: global-variables, code-analysis

right now I have a big project with legacy C/C++ source codes. There are many global variables spread in different functions. In order to analyze the code, I need a tool which can take a look into these functions, check what local/global variables are used and modified in this function, and then better show theses interfaces graphically.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of analysis and know accordingly the tool names? I've tried Understand from SciTools, but it cannot deliver this kind of report.

Thanks!